# TypeError: unorderable types: str() <= int()

Tags: python, typeerror, python-3.5

I am trying to take a list, `share_list`, and then cycle through the list one by one and produce an output tailored to the result. I have two problems: I don't know how to cycle through the list using a `for` loop, and I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Python Projects\DataAnalytics\algorithm.py", line 9, in <module>
    if check_pb_ratio.get_price_book() <= 1:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() <= int()
```

```
from yahoo_finance import Share

share_list = ['AAPL', 'GEVO', 'PTX']


for ticker in share_list:
    check_pb_ratio = Share(share_list[0])

    if check_pb_ratio.get_price_book() <= 1:
        print(str(check_pb_ratio.get_price_book()))
    else:
        print("P/B Ratio is too high.")
```

Comment: it seems that `check_pb_ratio.get_price_book()` is a string. try to print it before the `if`.

Comment: `share_list[0]` -> `ticker`, `check_pb_ratio.get_price_book()` -> `float(check_pb_ratio.get_price_book())`. Consider making use of google and/or a python tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason to this is that the function `check_pb_ratio.get_price_book()` returns a string, not an int. Python doesn't want to know the similarity between '1' and 1.
 So, the way to fix it is: add `int()` or `float()` around `check_pb_ratio.get_price_book()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Rawing

This code now works, I just need to fix a NoneType issue. Thanks!

```
from yahoo_finance import Share

share_list = ['AAPL', 'GEVO', 'PTX']


for ticker in share_list:
    check_pb_ratio = Share(ticker)

    if float(check_pb_ratio.get_price_book()) <= 1:
        print(str(check_pb_ratio.get_price_book()))
    else:
        print("P/B Ratio is too high.")
```